# Mysql Query Retrieve Table Column Titles then use in Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

This is a two-part question. I’m trying to replace variables in a string with values from a row of a database table. I’ve got this to work in the code below, but I have to hard write in each and every possible variable and replacement variable. Which would be fine, but I would like it a bit more automated so I could simply add a new column without having to go back into the code.

I assume the solution is to get the column title names into an array and then loop for each item in the array. Replacing the values for that loop and then moving to the next.

Here is what I have so far.

```
    $story_id = $_SESSION['story_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `story_id` = '$story_id'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $location = $row['location'];
    $mchar_gender = $row['mchar_gender'];
    $string = 'Client Gender: %mchar_gender%<br /> Client Location: %location%';
    $trans = array("%location%" => "$location", "%mchar_gender%" => "$mchar_gender"); 
    $new_string = strtr($string,$trans);
    }
       echo $new_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
    $string = str_replace('%'.$key.'%',  $value,  $string);
}
```

Did I get your question right?

Comment: Yes, that worked. I first had to get the $key from a previous query and then nestled the second query within along with your code.

And it seems to be working. Thank you so much.